# How to use two array use in single foreach

Tags: php, laravel

$created= [integer value]
$data = [integer and string value]

This is my code:

```
@foreach($data as $arraydata)
                    @foreach($created as $create)
                 <tr>
                    <td data-label="Column 1">{{$i}}</td>
                    <td data-label="Column 2">{{$arraydata['start']}}</td>
                    <td data-label="Column 3">{{$arraydata['finish']}}</td>
                    <td data-label="Column 4">{{$arraydata['rate']}}</td>
                    <td data-label="Column 5">{{$arraydata['subject']['subject']}}</td>
                    <td data-label="Column 6">{{$arraydata['total_session']}}</td>
                    <td data-label="Column 7">{{$arraydata['amount']}}</td>
                    <td data-label="Column 7">{{$create['created_at']}}</td>
                 </tr>
                    @php
                        $i++
                    @endphp
                @endforeach
                @endforeach
```

How i can use in single foreach loop

Comment: You can remove inner foreach and add <td data-label="Column 7">{{$created[$i-1]['created_at']}}</td>

Comment: can u post the $created and $data, so we can know the real structure.

Comment: If any of the below posts have answered your question please may you mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
@foreach($data as $index=>$arraydata)
<tr>
    <td data-label="Column 1">{{++$i}}</td>
    <td data-label="Column 2">{{$arraydata['start']}}</td>
    <td data-label="Column 3">{{$arraydata['finish']}}</td>
    <td data-label="Column 4">{{$arraydata['rate']}}</td>
    <td data-label="Column 5">{{$arraydata['subject']['subject']}}</td>
    <td data-label="Column 6">{{$arraydata['total_session']}}</td>
    <td data-label="Column 7">{{$arraydata['amount']}}</td>
    <td data-label="Column 7">{{$created[$index]['created_at']}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: @GhulamHaiderFarooqi If this has answered your question please may you mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Yes @GhulamHaiderFarooqi in case it works please check on Tick to make it Green Tick (accepted answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try This method:

```
public function showDetails($id) {
        $users = array();
        $profiles= Profile::where(['profile_id' => $id])->get();
        $managers = Manager::where(['manager_id' => $id])->get();
        foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
            $profile = array('email' => $profile->user->email, 'name' => $profile->user->firstname);
            $users[] = $profile;
        }
        foreach ($managers as $manager) {
            $manager = array('email' => $manager->email, 'name' => $manager->name);
            $users[] = $manager ;
        }
        return view('custom-view', compact('users'));
    }
```